# Predicates and Quantifiers_Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

Prove That 
∃x (A(x) → B(x)) ≡ ∀x A(x) → ∃x B(x).

My Attempt -:
RHS will be always **true** as in  ∀x A(x) → ∃x B(x),∀x A(x) will be always false as not "All"number in the **Universe of discourse** will satisfy A(x).

coming on LHS it can be True or false ..please help me out

Comment: Same error as other question ... You have to prove it: the *equivalence* means that either both formulae are *true* or both false*, not that they must be always true.

Answer (score 1):

$$\exists x(A(x)\to B(x))\equiv\exists x(\neg A(x)\lor B(x))\equiv\exists x\neg A(x)\lor\exists xB(x)\equiv\neg\forall xA(x)\lor\exists xB(x)\equiv\forall xA(x)\to\exists xB(x)$$

Comment: Thats correct ..but can you help me out at the point where i am stuck ..@bof

Comment: If Bx is true in LHS then LHS is true and hence Making RHS equal (as conclusion part contains Bx in RHs which is true),we are done with TRUE. Now for FALSE part,if Ax is TRUE FALSE ..then LHS will be TRUE and RHS will be TRUE

Comment: A(x)=x is even  ,B(x)=x is odd